# Griddle/Grill pan

Tags: equipment

I have one of these cast iron grill/griddle pans... the griddle is fine, however, the grill section has a good deal of build up in-between the grill lines.  Some of it is coming off just by using a spatula and I don't want the black bits on my food.  I tried to clean this but all of the suggestions are not working. Can I scrape off the black stuff and reseason?

Comment: If it doesn't clean up with a stiff brush (stiff plastic, or a brass brush), it might be easier to strip the whole thing, and re-season : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/11598/67 .  (but if you can scrape it clean, go that route.  No sense in removing seasoning if you don't have to).

Answer (score 1):

Cast iron responds well to sanding. I thought I had damaged my c.i. frying pan because of pitting - I *thought* in the metal. So I decided to re-sand the thing by hand.  Turned out the pits were only in the "seasoning" layer. Sanded it smooth, finishing up with fine sand paper & steel wool if i remember right.  Anyway all by hand.  Seasoning layer turns out to be pretty soft.  Whole thing took a few days, on and off.  Re-seasoned, & all right again now.

Comment: Typically the seasoning is the problem w/ grill pans -- you get grease build up in the corners, and it polymerizes.  As you're not regularly scraping it, it doesn't get knocked down like the surface of a griddle would.