# Scale build up on outside of cast iron skillet

Tags: cast-iron

I have an old used cast iron skillet that is good on the inside but it has build up lumps on the outside. How do I get that off?

Comment: That sucks.  There's a question here about [stripping cast iron](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11592/67), but that's going to ruin the inside, too.  You might try going at it with a steel wire brush, and see if you can knock down the lumps some.

Comment: Any chance that we could get either an update on what you ended up doing, or a picture of it to assess the severity of the build up?