# Can I still use this old skillet? Was rusty, gave it a clean but there are still big black splotches?

Tags: cast-iron, skillet

[image]

I've had this skillet for ages and never used it. Unfortunately it went rusty. I've given it a big clean and gotten rid of the rust, but black splotches seem to have seeped into the iron and will not come off. Can I still use this pan if I season it well?
Thanks in advance
Lucy

Comment: in addition to whatever other answers you get, you can use steel wool (or your preferred method) to remove the rust/seasoning and reseason it, at which point it should be as good as new. We have a bunch of other questions on this site about restoring cast-iron cookware, check them out!

Comment: I'd suggest this one for residual whatever removal: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11592/34242 And this one for seasoning once the whatever is gone: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/641/34242