# What is the purpose of using potato peels for seasoning a cast iron pan?

Tags: cast-iron, seasoning-pans

My first ever cast iron pan just arrived. The package contains following seasoning directions.

> 1. Wash with clothes detergent (not soap or dish detergent) to remove the
>      rust protection coating.
> 2. Wash thoroughly with warm water to remove detergent. Dry pan.
> 3. Fill the pan with fresh potato peels. Pour sunflower oil or rape oil
>      on them, until it is almost full with
>      oil.
> 4. Leave the pan with the potato peels and oil for an hour on the
>      next-to-highest setting on the stove
>      top.
> 5. Throw away the potato peels and oil, dry the pan with kitchen paper
> 6. Coat the pan with a thin layer of sunflower or rape oil.

Not only don't I want to spend the afternoon peeling potatoes and then throw away most of them (I cannot eat the amount of potatoes needed for these peels), but even the positive amazon reviews for the pan all warn before the stench the charring peels produce during the seasoning: `It lingered for about three days although I changed the fume hood filters, but it is a small price to pay for such a great pan`. For me, it is a big price, because I have no fume hood, and there is no door between the kitchenette and the living room/bedroom. I looked up advise on seasoning pans, hoping for some trick, and found [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/641/whats-the-best-way-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet) where the accepted answer doesn't include potato peels (in fact, no answer mentions them).

Now I am unsure whether to use them. On the one hand, I don't want to deal with the side effects. On the other hand, a producer is supposed to know what is best for his products. I don't want to get poisoned by an anti-rust coating residue that would have been rendered harmless in a chemical reaction with potato peels. Besides, I can't use the seasoning process outlined in the question I linked, because my pan doesn't fit in my oven.

I guess it would be easier to decide if I knew of their purpose. Does any of you know of using potato peels for seasoning pans, and can you tell me why they are needed? Or is it just an urban legend the ignorant manufacturer printed in the manual (the pan is not a well-known brand, maybe some hardware manufacturer decided it will be easy to add pans to their product line and made them without gathering enough know-how).

Comment: Can you tell us which brand?

Comment: Cast iron usually comes pre-seasoned rather that rust protected, are you sure you got cast iron?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I personally had never heard of it, but after doing some research online, I found another [set of instructions that called for boiling potatoes in the pan before seasoning](http://backyardbushman.com/?p=710):

> After boiling potato peelings for 15
>   minutes, the skillet had a nasty
>   slurry of grey looking sand in the
>   bottom  Once the skillet was heated,
>   the pores were opened, and the
>   starchy/water mixture was able to draw
>   out oils and dirt that I was not
>   capable of getting to through normal
>   washing. I fully do not understand the
>   science behind why the starch/water
>   mixture did this, but the experience
>   was enough to convince me of the need
>   to do this. So much in fact, that I
>   did this process twice on each
>   skillet.

I read a few too many web pages while researching this, and didn't save all of the links, but I did notice a few things:

1. Some of the posts kept switching between saying cast iron and carbon steel; both are typically seasoned, but they're different materials, so I don't know if it's recommended for both, or if people were mixing things up.  (I only have one carbon steel item, a wok, which I got second hand, so had already had its first seasoning).
2. Some of the posts mentioned boiling potatoes for 15 minutes, other mentioned frying potatoes as the first thing to be cooked in the pan (in oil), some mentioned cooking them 'til they burn.  The boiling potatoes ones also mentioned it works for cleaning stainless steel pans.
3. Some mentioned peels specifically, others say that you can use any part of the potato ... if it's the starch that's of interest, I'd think the middle would actually be better, but I'm guessing that the peels were considered waste, and so considered a less valuable item; I'd be inclined to just use one potato, dispatched with a peeler, if you were trying to avoid wasting potatoes you weren't going to eat.

Comment: Thank you very much! After reading your link, I decided to try boiling first and frying second. Instead of peels, I sliced whole unpeeled potatoes on the mandoline. I can confirm that a greyish sludge develops during boiling potatoes in the unseasoned pan, so I guess it was a good idea to do it. Frying didn't produce a visible effect except for the smoke (and that was violently visible despite of open windows and doors on all sides). Conclusion: I will always do the boiling from now on, just to be sure.

Comment: I wonder, was they gray stuff... iron?

Comment: @derobert : I've seen grey sludge when cleaning grease off of a cast iron pan that had sat out of a day or two.  (the grease had climbed up the sides of the pan, but wasn't really obvious 'til I started cleaning it, and it just got kinda strange and sticky and was PITA to get off ... but it made me think of this question)

Answer (score 7):

I've never heard of such a thing.  As one who has seasoned a few cast iron pans, I can tell you that you don't need the potato peals.  Just coat it with oil and bake it.  [Here's](http://www.howtodothings.com/food-and-drink/a3371-how-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet.html) one of the first hits I got on Google.  That's all you need to do.

Comment: or call in a favour from a friend to borrow their oven for a while if it doesn't fit inside yours?

Comment: @raven It could be that the producer knows something Google doesn't - at least, boiling (instead of frying) the potatoes definitely provoked some kind of material leeching into the potatoes, turning them grey.

Comment: @KimbaF It is true that I only have a small toast oven. But my purchase is a 28 cm pan with a 27 cm handle, thus needing an oven which is either 55 cm wide or has a 67 cm diagonal. I don't think any of my friends has such a monster. Anyway, I somehow succeeded seasoning it on the stovetop, despite the fact that the pan surface got 95°C at setting "3" and 220°C at setting "4". After that, I just ordered an induction cooking unit which can heat in steps of 20°C o.0

Comment: @rumtscho: Wait, a half-sheet is something like 35×50cm, an oven that fits that is hardly a monster... And 220°C is a little lower than I'd use to season cast iron in the oven, but it'll probably work if left long enough.

Comment: @derobert Oh, I didn't know that the "stuff is bigger in America" rule extended to ovens. A standard oven here is 44x37 cm, with a ~57.5 cm diagonal. I admit I made a mistake in calculating the diagonal needed above, it is actually ~62.2 cm (including a 2cm width of the handle end) so still not enough. A 35x50 cm oven is also too small if we want to lay the pan horizontally. We'd get it in if we wedged it in at an angle to the bottom, but I doubt that an oven's owner would appreciate the resulting burned oil marks from where the pan touched the sides of the oven.

Comment: @rumtscho: Yeah, I measured mine, and it's something like 55×60cm (which is a little on the small side here), so it surprised me to hear of some cast iron that wouldn't fit in an oven ("does it require a team to lift?") We have counter-top "toaster" ovens which are much smaller, too (but its not weird to have both)

Answer (score 4):

From what i understand, NEW pans come coated with a wax or lacquer to prevent them from rusting after manufacture. The boiled potato peel water removes this layer. You do not need to fry them, just bring them to light boil in the pan and then after about 15 mins, use the hot potato peel water to wash the pan surfaces. You then rinse the pan "in very hot water" and then dry the pan and start your seasoning protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out from Americas Test Kitchen.  Instruction for season are about 2/3's into the youtube. They recommend using oil, salt and potato peels at the same time over medium heat. Once the peels have browned you throw it all out and wipe it down.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-suTmUX4Vbk

Comment: Santos Murillo, welcome to Seasoned Advice! Please don't post answers where the information is hidden in an outside link. The Internet is ever changing and what works today may be a broken link tomorrow, rendering your answer basically useless. Linking to the video is fine, but the essential information should always be *right in the answer*. So please [edit] your post with the important facts from the ATC video, thanks. Let me suggest you also take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about how this site works. I'm looking foreward to more contributions from you!

Comment: Actually, the instructions were at roughly the 2 minute mark (of a 5min 51sec video).  They used a mix of salt, oil & potato peals to both strip the coating that it was shipped with, and give it its first seasoning.

Comment: Also worth mentioning -- they were specifically discussing carbon steel pans, but I would suspect that the grease used for shipping is similar.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, not willing to read every line, but first off, the coating is beeswax, so it should not kill you, at least it was on my pan. We used very hot tap water and a rough sponge. I have read others have boiled water and poured it over the pan.

Yes the salt, oil, two tater skins does smoke up a kitchen. We got no lingering smell after an hour, did have to get a fan to blow out the smoke.

I don’t know why but the oil, salt, potato skins actually worked, yes the skins turn to “carbon” black.The skins seem to help move the salt up on the sides, I’m not sure if any chemical or catalyst reaction is going on. It does simulate cooking something.

It worked out well, other then getting fussed at by the wife.

My advice too, get a small outdoor grill and do the initial seasoning.

It’s not carbon,”The seasoning on cast iron is formed by fat polymerization, fat polymerization is maximized with a drying oil, and flaxseed oil is the only drying oil that’s edible. From that I deduced that flaxseed oil would be the ideal oil for seasoning cast iron.”
Source http://sherylcanter.com/wordpress/2010/01/a-science-based-technique-for-seasoning-cast-iron/comment-page-9/

Answer (score 0):

I am the same, in that I have never heard of seasoning with potato skins. As a process I use on my omelete pans that are cast iron which will prevent sticking , is that I cover the bottom with table salt. Bring up to heat then reduce temperature not to create to much smoke. Keep moving the salt and you will find that it starts getting darker which is the impurities being drawn out. Salt for about 5 mins, pour salt into a heat resistant container as the heat will melt and scold. Wipe clean, drizzle with oil , bring to heat and wipe over the entire inside of the pan so the oil soaks in and it is seasoned.
Do process regularly to maintain quality.

Comment: Dry salt on a dry surface doesn't draw anything out. If you put salt in a dry pan and heat it, the only thing that could cause the salt to darken is organic material on the surface of the pan burning to leave carbon deposits on the surface of the salt, and the smoke that you see. If you heated dry salt on perfectly clean iron to any temperature you can achieve in a kitchen, absolutely nothing would happen.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been strictly with cast iron (not carbon steel - there seems to be some intermixing of the terms here). I had also not heard of the potato seasoning method (again, there is a mix of using the potato to clean and/or season here).

I noticed that no-one actually answered the question regarding the purpose of the potato (chemical reaction to pan for seasoning) and I suspect the potato and or starch is merely a cleaning agent and NOT a seasoning agent. I personally have tried many types of oil at different temps - what I have found best: is use an outdoor grill get the pan to 400+ degrees (this will also burn off any wax or shipping coating) THEN apply the oil (flaxseed or other high smoke point) and let season for an hour at 400+ (I like 500). Please be careful the pan is HOT when you apply the oil and will smoke during seasoning.

Think about how you will apply before hand - I use a 100% white cotton towel, dip in oil, spread on pan using long tongs. wear long fireplace gives or long oven mitts).  Allow to cool and you will have a shiny black 1st seasoning. This seasoning does not flake off which happens when seasoning at too low of a temp for too short a time - ironically Lodge's instructions have not resulted in good seasoning for me. Then cook with pan using coconut, peanut, grapeseed or another high smoke point oil or animal fat (think bacon, butter, steaks etc) and the pan will continue to season. FYI never fry with olive oil - this is best used as a base in dressings or drizzled on the cooked food. No need to "wash" your seasoned cast-iron pan after cooking - just wipe out immediately after cooking.

Answer (score 0):

I had took my dog outside and forgot my skillet on a hot burner, I use oil, kosher salt, and slice the end off a potato, scrubbing with the potato then reseason in the oven upside down over a baking sheet 3 times with a layer of oil on 300 DEGREES, always works perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  I'm afraid your answer doesn't really address the question, though, which is also 10 years old and has an accepted answer.  Try reading carefully what the question is asking in the future and address that directly.