# Having a hard time seasoning an iron skillet. Sticky seasoning

Tags: seasoning-pans

EDIT: The other question speaks about seasoning in oven. I cannot fit my skillet in any oven. It's big with a plastic handle.

I have an iron skillet and I have no idea how to season it properly. I once washed the skillet cause the oil buildup was too much and then gave a real hard wash. Now the Skilelt won't season. The seasoning gets kinda sticky and little lines appear or hardened oil.

What is the proper way to season the skillet on Gas Stove?

This is how I am trying now.

1. Wash the skillet clean.
2. Add a thin film of oil and wipe the excess oil.
3. Heat the skillet till it smokes.

I have tried heating the skilelt to high temp first and the result is still the same. The seasoning gets sticky.

Comment: Wrong oil? See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13555/what-oil-is-best-for-seasoning-a-cast-iron-skillet?rq=1 [though I don't agree with the accepted answer, I personally think it's about the worst for 'soft/sticky'; read further down.] BTW, seasoning doesn't wash off, you need to sand it off. If it did, it wasn't done properly.

Comment: @unlisted I am using Mustard oil or Rice Bran Oil. I used lemon and metal sponge to clean the skillet like how it was when it was new.

Comment: Or this one: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/641/34242

Comment: There is no difference between seasoning in an oven and on stovetop, the oven is just less error-prone, but else the process is the same, so there is no sense to keep the question open. You are already doing the proper steps anyway, so you won't get any written answers that can tell you more, from here on it is a matter of temperature control. You can go through our questions on seasoning pans, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seasoning-pans, in case you want to catch some extra tidbits.

Comment: @rumtscho Do I need to heat the pan at high flame and for long do I heat it? High flame or medium flame? I have no idea. Why my seasoning is coming as sticky then?

Comment: @4-K both high and medium flame will work. You have to heat it until it is done, no matter how long it takes. "Done" is something you can tell by experience. If you don't have the experience, you have to either have somebody physically present to show it to you, or work by trial and error.

Comment: if it's sticky, you can just heat it again and leave it for a bit longer, until it stops being sticky. stickiness mostly means you used too much oil or didn't heat it for long enough.

Comment: Common error which I'll suspect from the "until it smokes" descriptor is going too hot, rather than hot enough for long enough; or thinking that too hot for less time is just as good as hot enough for long enough. If the plastic handle is not oven safe, remove it (and the pan was poorly designed...)