# How to stop my cupcakes from sticking to their cupcake wrappers?

Tags: baking, cupcakes

I have found that every time I make cupcakes (or muffins, cornbread & hot dog muffins, etc) that the paper liner sticks to the finished cupcake. I know its not me because the Tim Hortons 'muffins' also stick to their liners.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You want to kill the experience of scraping the remainder of muffin from the wrapper with spoon/fingers/teeth? You barbarian!

Comment: There was an edit to this question which really turned it into an answer; please feel free to post an additional *answer*, but don't remove the question itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Isn't that normal?

I suppose if it's causing a problem, you could use a non-stick (teflon, etc.) muffin pan, without the paper liners.

You could also try silicone-coated (parchment) liners. A quick check reveals that e.g., Amazon sells them.

<purist>cornbread shall be cooked in preheated cast iron, and if that's sticking, you need to [season your cast iron properly](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/641/whats-the-best-way-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet).</purist>

Comment: Thanks... and they were muffins with cut up hot dogs and corn... really good... and bite sized :D

Answer (score 10):

I've had this happen too and I've found this little trick helps.  Line your muffin/cupcake tin with your papers and then give the papers in the pan a light coating with non-stick spray.

Answer (score 5):

If you put them upside down into the microwave under a wet paper towel for 15 seconds, the cupcake papers come right off.

Answer (score 5):

One question would be why do you need the wrappers?  If you don't need them at all, just grease the pans and don't use them.

I once agreed to make cupcakes for a wedding**, and as I knew this was a potential problem (and I didn't want people dressed nicely having to struggle with unwrapping frosted cupcakes), I greased the muffin tins, and purchased larger than normal wrappers.  Once the cupcakes were baked, I removed them from the pan, and just placed them in the wrappers.

** I actually agreed to make a cake.  I was told 'just a plain white cake'.  So I took 3 months of cake decorating classes.  Then somehow it changed to '150 cupcakes, with a rose on each one' ... luckily, I found a place where I could buy the roses, but I had to clean 'em out.

Comment: I agree, I never use wrappers myself for muffins or cupcakes.  Instead, I spray the pans with cooking spray; I find the cupcakes release just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the silicone baking cup liners? My wife and daughter used it whenever they bake muffins and banana bread and with perfect result, no burnt side and bottom and evenly cooked muffins  non-sticky and easy to slide cupcakes and banana breads. You don't need to buy paper cupcake liners everytime because silicone cupcake liners are reusable and easy to clean. To learn more see...
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00P87R4PO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P87R4PO)

Answer (score 2):

I second the non-stick spray.  Another suggestion would be putting a water bath in to keep the muffins or cupcakes from drying out too much and sticking to the paper.

Answer (score 1):

I've found cooking them in paper cases and silicone cases seems to stop them sticking. I think the silicone stops the moisture escaping and the paper means they don't stick to the silicone.

Comment: The question is how to keep them from sticking to the paper liner.

Comment: Put the paper inside a silicone mould. I think the silicone stops them from drying out in the over which seems to make  them more likely to stick.

Answer (score 1):

Slide a cookie sheet filled with water under the bottom rack. The moisture in the oven prevents the muffin from sticking to the paper liners.

Comment: Never heard of that one! I'll have to give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

My muffin recipe calls for melted butter, so I brush a little into the bottom of the wrappers and up the sides a bit. Works a treat. I've also seen greaseproof silicone ones that might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Using tin foil type liners instead of paper ones has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon Wilton parchment paper cupcake liners and voila!, no sticking to the paper.  Something must be different though because cupcakes never used to stick to paper liners like they do now.  The parchment works great though.  Jo-Ann's sells them and you can find them in stores where Wilton products are sold.

Answer (score 0):

I used both paper liners and the foil outer they did not stick.  Then I bought cheaper paper and they stuck really bad.