# Maintaining sizzler plate

Tags: mexican-cuisine, utensils, american-cuisine

i purchased sizzler plate last month. I am using it once or twice in a week. However it is getting lots of rust on it. within 5 minutes of washing plate, it turns back to rust one. I am using lemon juice for a while and it does the trick.

But i am looking for some permanent solution for this.

Thanks for stopping by....!!!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "sizzler plate". Is it cast iron? Do you have a picture or can you offer a link that describes exactly what you have?

Comment: Yes...cast iron as plate with wooden holder.

Comment: You'll find most of what you need here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/641/whats-the-best-way-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet. There is a lot more info on cast iron here, just search for "cast iron"

Comment: The key to caring for your plate is that cast iron needs to be treated differently than other materials you might be used to. It's easy once you know what you're doing, and you'll love your plate once you've gotten used to treating it right.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: That was very helpful. Thanks a lot friend...!!! :)

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm voting now to close this question because the information needed to answer it is already here, but I hope you keep coming back.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite simple. After you have cleaned it, simply coat it lightly with vegetable oil. You can rub it on with your fingertips or a paper towel.

Answer (score -1):

Dry it in the oven for a little while after washing and before oiling, as it will rust if not completely dry. The oil is good to prevent rust.