# How to reseason cast iron skillets using a fire

Tags: equipment

I was told to put my cast iron skillets in an open fire to clean.  We did and now they have a red discoloration and look worse than before.  How do I clean the red off and get them shiny again?

Comment: Can you post an image? I'm not sure why your skillet would turn red.

Comment: After firing, you will need to re-season. See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/641/whats-the-best-way-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet

Comment: Welcome! As @Catija notes a picture would be a great help. It's possible for a cast iron pan to be ruined if overheated in a fire and then exhibit a red discoloration. But we can't even venture a guess without a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Have they simply rusted? Clean cast iron or steel without oil (having been burned off in the fire) will rust at the least provocation.

Steel wool and oil should clean that off (it also requires "elbow grease") - use whatever oil you intend to re-season them with.