# Cast Iron Skillet with Lid Rusted togethe

Tags: cast-iron

I want to use my mom's cast iron skillet which she used primarily for frying chicken but the lid is sealed/rusted/won't come off from the skillet.  How can I get this lid off without breaking it?

Comment: Welcome to [cooking.se]! **;-)** This is more of a [diy.se] question than a cooking question, but if it's an enamelled cast iron pot you might try submerging it upside-down in a battery acid solution overnight.  (Use gloves!)

Answer (score 11):

There is a product called Naval Jelly that is designed to remove rust from metal items.  Its available in our area at most hardware stores.  Menards has it. Use a toothbrush to work the jelly in between the lid and the skillet and let it sit for 10-15 minutes.  It literally changes the rust into a water-soluable paste that you can wipe away with a clean, wet cloth.  Then you will be able to season your skillet (and lid) so it can be usable again. Hope this works for you.

Comment: And for seasoning (and possibly further stripping) cast iron pans, see : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/641/67

Comment: Thanks Joe! I haven't learned how to reference previous answers yet.

Comment: At the bottom of the question or answer you want to reference, there will be a 'share' link, which will give you a URL that you can copy and paste into another question / answer / comment.