# Residue on a new hard-nitriding cast iron skillet

Tags: cast-iron, carbon-steel

I have just purchased a new hard-nitriding cast iron skillet at a HomeGoods store (Brandani brand), and i'm having problems cleaning it before the first use. I've spent hours and hours washing it with soap, subbing with steel cloth, scrubbing more with salt and oil, and yet every time i dry it and then slide wet paper towel across, it gets black residue. The surface looks sliver'ish not dark, no idea why it emits dark residue, and why it still emits it after literally hours of washing and cleaning. Any ideas?

Also, despite saying it's cast iron, it feels more like thick carbon steel.

UPDATE: I ended up returning the skillet; my main concern is that Brandani brand is not known much and there is no guarantee the material (wherever it's carbon steel or some composite) is safe, as it feels like a Chinese knock off.

Comment: Stop washing it & season it. It is carbon steel. not cast iron. Same method for both - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/641/whats-the-best-way-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet

Comment: @unlisted do you know what that black residue is and where it's coming from? I am concerned that after seasoning it might still leak into food if/when seasoning thins during cooking

Comment: A quick google search on that pan found a myriad complaints of the same thing - all went away once people stopped washing it & started seasoning it. Whatever the nitrous coating does for the surface, it's apparently not very water-proof… just like any iron/steel pan surface.

Comment: unlisted, that sounds like an answer, care to post it?

Comment: "hard nitriding" is sales BS; no place in cookware. Nitriding is very thin ( < 0.001 " thick ), very hard layer used on cutting tools like drill bits.