# Is it safe to deglace a cast-iron pan?

Tags: cast-iron

I've heard that pouring a cold liquid into a very hot cast-iron pan can destroy it (because it's more brittle than a steel pan for instance). Is that true or do most of you deglace in cast-iron pans as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A metal pan will not crack simply from cold liquid.  If you heat it up to a very high temperature and *submerge* it in cold water, that's not such a good idea.  But deglazing is just a tiny amount of liquid.

Now, aluminum is another story - if it's hot enough and you pour cold water (or cold anything) on it, it can *warp*, even with a relatively small amount of liquid.  And for Teflon and other "coated" cookware, you can ruin the coating that way.  But heavier steel or cast iron - no way.

If you're really concerned, just keep the deglazing liquid at room temperature.  Deglazing is usually done with vinegar and you keep that at room temperature anyway, right?  I deglaze my CI all the time with cider vinegar and have never experienced even the tiniest crack in 10 years.  I'm pretty sure it's safe.  It's great, actually; CI deglazes very easily, you just need a small splash of vinegar.

Comment: I've never deglazed with vinegar -- but I've had no problems with years of using water, broth or alcohol.  Deglazing is actually my preferred way of cleaning my cast iron: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/261/how-do-you-clean-a-cast-iron-skillet/509#509

Comment: +1 Didn't know that about coated materials, do you know if the coating comes off in that situation or is it ruined and just stays on?

Comment: Interesting @Joe, I think I *only* use vinegar (I always have cider vinegar around for this purpose).  Of course you can deglaze with anything, especially on cast iron where the browned bits aren't even really stuck.  All of the things you list can also be kept at room temperature if you happen to be paranoid!

Comment: @kryptic: It's hard to say for sure because every coating is different and the companies don't really disclose a lot of information about them.  Some coatings don't even need the water, they'll leach into the food with just a high enough heat.  Others don't readily leach into solids but are easily absorbed by water.  It's partly because of all these unknowns that I tend to eschew the chemical non-stick coatings for all but the most basic cooking tasks (mainly frying on low to medium heat).

Comment: @Aaronut - And for a bonus when you use vinegar you get some extra iron in your diet. :)

Comment: @Sobachatina: I could be mistaken, but I don't think that a small splash will actually leech off the iron; it might wear off some of the seasoning but I haven't had problems in that respect either.

Comment: I, in fact, always use cast iron if I plan on deglazing. I find that the cast iron produces more of the little stuck-on bits of food that make a sauce from deglazing much better.

Comment: Vinegar will almost certainly remove some of the cast iron's seasoning. If you must do it, be prepared to re-season.

Comment: @keith: I've been doing it for years and have never had to re-season. YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Cast iron is more brittle, sure, but cast iron is practically indestructible, so that's like saying "diamond is more brittle than jello". You probably *could* shatter it, if you tried really hard, but there is no way you'd do it just by dumping a little liquid into the pan, while it's at a normal cooking temperature. Even if it was way beyond a normal cooking temp, throwing liquid in the pan would just cause some really energetic steam.

Now, run it up to 1000 degrees or so, then lob it into a bathtub full of icewater, it'd probably shatter.