# Cast iron pan rusts during seasoning

Tags: cast-iron, seasoning-pans

I had a cast iron pan that I wanted to strip and reseason. I stripped it using the oven cleaner method and then I dried it in the oven at 200C. It got super rusty but I was able to get that all off with oil and a paper towel. The oil I am using is a mix of Canola and Soybean.

This is where the problems start. So I oiled it (just a thin layer and wiped up the excess) and put it in the oven at 400C for two hours. It came out with this dark orange rusty color. Its certainly got a layer of seasoning on it. Wiping it with a paper towel doesnt surface any rust.

So I stripped it with vinegar. While it was still wet I coated it in a bunch of oil. Then I stuck it in the oven at 200 for 15-20 minutes. When it came out there was just a touch of rust. That came off with more oil and elbow grease. Then I added a thick layer of oil, I didnt wipe it off. This time I cooked it at 400C for an hour and a half AND THERE IS STILL THE RUSTY SHEEN.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You never removed the initial rust layer from stripping the seasoning. Wiping it down with oil and a paper towel will just mask the appearance of the rust, not remove it. To remove the rust, you will need to scrub the entire pan with something abrasive, such as steel wool.

Edit: You may find the answers to this related [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/71736/how-did-rust-appear-on-my-cast-iron-in-a-matter-of-minutes?rq=1) useful.

Comment: So the second time I tried this I scrubbed off all the rust and hit it with a paper towel and oil to simultaneously try to dry what I could and oil it so it didnt rust. When I was done with that there was no rust. Then I put it in the oven to dry it and when it came out there was a little rust.

Comment: Are you suggesting I remove that rust by using steal wool and oil? Also im pretty sure I took the rust off because when I started with the paper towels they came back red and when I finished they came back grey/black.

Comment: @FailureGod The rust is not on the surface of the pan: It is the surface of the pan. You can wipe off some of the dust with a paper towel, but to remove it all you need to scrape off the top layer of metal. You cannot do this with a paper towel. You need to use something like steel wool to do that. No need for oil in that stage, just elbow grease ;)