# The cast iron pan changed color after machine-dishwashing

Tags: cleaning, cast-iron, pan

My cast iron pan is new, clearly black, like deeply black. In the instructions, it is mentioned that it can be put in a dishwasher (not recommended, but it could be). The first time putting it in the dishwasher, it was really catastrophic, rust everywhere, like it was covered with rust powder.

I washed it manually (using vinegar and bicarbonate powder) and re-seasoned it. But the color of the pan clearly changed to a slight gold (or maybe slight red), not really black as before.

What happened? Any way to restore the original color?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I bought a cast iron skillet and after washing it and then heating it I got a color like rust](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/108703/i-bought-a-cast-iron-skillet-and-after-washing-it-and-then-heating-it-i-got-a-co)

Comment: @Sneftel No. Since I already cleaned and re-seasoned it three times, no improvement was noted in the color.

Comment: Really can't see anything vaguely useful in those tiny pictures. Have you got something with better resolution?

Comment: Many dishwashing powders are intended to scour off debris.  This can damage the seasoning on cast iron pans, particularly if you have a ‘slick’ seasoning (vs a ‘hard’ seasoning)

Comment: Also, I think you learned not to put cast iron in the dishwasher.

Comment: @FuzzyChef For sure, and in the hardest way :( I also learned not to entrust blindly the instructions coming with ...

Comment: @Tetsujin All that you need is to notice the color difference. Deep black (before) then slightly tinted orange-brown (after). Sorry, the order was inverted.

Comment: Are we looking at the *inside* or the *outside* of the pan? The letters etc. confuse me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a layer of seasoning that hasn’t fully cured, it’s often an orange tinge.  You typically only see this when doing the initial seasoning on new (or stripped) pans.

Continued use of the pan, as it heats to the necessary temperature, will get it to turn fully black.  If it doesn’t, you can always put it in the oven to cure.

Comment: And I should mention— this assumes that you had shiny metal when you started re-seasoning it.  If there was still rust, you’re going to want to strip it down to bare metal and start again

Comment: I cleaned it really hard, but the color is still slightly tinted orange-brown. Even after three times reseasonning on the oven.
And when you say "you’re going to want to strip it down to bare metal", does it mean rebutting it in the dishwasher? (or how)
Maybe it's totally normal (meaning that the color is not really coming from the rust), and all I need is just more patience to have the deep black original color. I'm confused.

Comment: @Sofiane : you want something that isn’t going to cause more rust in the process.  See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/11598/67

Comment: And cleaning is going to leave it orangey brown.  You need to heat it to the right point to get it to turn black (but not over heat it, which will cause it to break down again)

Comment: Thank you. Any recommendation about the "right point"? I ask because I no more have confidence in the instructions coming with (since it is already indicated that it is possible to put it in the dishwasher).

Comment: @Sofiane I think it’s around 350-400°F / 175-205°C, but I’ve seen recommendations to bake the seasoning anywhere from 250-500°F, and lower temps lead to that orange-brown coating.  I also don’t know if it’s a function of the type of oil used

Comment: FWIW, when I've reconditioned cast iron, I put it on my grill outside so that I can get it to 250C/500F, and then I do 3-4 coats.   But it doesn't turn black immediately, more of a very dark brown.

Comment: @FuzzyChef : and it’s worth mentioning that brown and orange are related colors, only differing in intensity / subjective backgrounds: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wh4aWZRtTwU