# How to recover a cast-iron pot?

Tags: cleaning, cast-iron

I heated up a cast-iron pot in an oven and might have burnt the lid. Is it possible to restore it back to its formal glory?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7127/how-to-clean-a-burnt-cast-iron-pot?rq=1

Comment: @MarkWildon, this isn't a dup. because the OP has incorrectly identified her pot as cost iron, when it is an enameled cast iron (slightly different care and maintenance) and is answered below. The link you described has great info but not applicable here, as those tips don't apply to this particular issue.

Answer (score 4):

That is an enameled cast iron pot. I often have the same issue and find that it fairly easily comes off using a green 3M nylon scrub, a little dish soap and some elbow grease. If necessary you can also apply some baking powder or Bar Keeper's Friend.

It shouldn't take too much effort to get it off.

Comment: +1 exactly what I would write. I would only add that you should get the water as hot as you can possibly stand. I found it helps in my experience.