# Can deglazing a cast iron skillet remove the seasoning?

Tags: cast-iron

I would love to combine two of the best things in cooking, deglazing with a fonds or wine and my cast iron skillet, which I have been seasoning for a couple of months now. My concern is that the seasoning might remove the seasoning from the skillet. Could this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's properly seasoned, and affixed well to the pan, there shouldn't be any problem.

In fact, it's what I typically use to [clean my pans](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/261/how-do-you-clean-a-cast-iron-skillet/509#509) even if I'm not making a sauce.

If you're reducing a sauce that's highly acidic, you might have cause for concern, as you don't want to have acids in the pan for long periods.

Comment: Great! I deglazed the skillet for the first time tonight and everything went well. The sauce was delicious. I just added some butter and red wine to the still hot (but not maximum hot) skillet and it all started cooking immediately, reducing to a nice sauce. The seasoning didn't seem to suffer the least bit. Also, the skillet was basically completely clean after deglazing. Just had to rinse with some water and wipe dry, while I usually have to actively (cautiously) scrub away remaining residue.