# How to clean a wooden cauldron lid?

Tags: cleaning, wood

I bought [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwUQn.jpg) the other day for making shabu shabu (샤부샤부) as well as for camping.  The pot itself is made of cast iron which I know [how to clean](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/261/19921), but the lid is made of wood.  The lid doesn't get very dirty during use - but there are some splatters, etc - I'm wondering if I should wipe this down with oil or just water?  I would use oil, but I'm concerned that this will inhibit the wood's ability to swell when placed over steaming liquid.

Answer (score 4):

Beautiful. If it were mine it would usually get cleaned with a quick wipe with a slightly damp paper towel. On the rare occasions that it needed it, it would get sponged with soapy water, rinsed, and lightly oiled as it dried.